# Multiple Instance of a Wpf usercontrol , all uses the same routed Event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple usercontrol, inside my usercontrol I have two button like this

```
      <Button Name="elDownStepTgBtn"    Click="HandleButtonClick1" ></Button>
      <Button Name="elUpStepTgBtn"      Click="HandleButtonClick2"  ></Button>
```

in the code behind I implement two routed event for my buttons: `decreaseEvent` and `increaseEvent` ,

```
    public partial class UpDownUc :UserControl
{
    
    public UpDownUc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    // Create RoutedEvent
    // This creates a static property on the UserControl, SettingsConfirmedEvent, which 
    // will be used by the Window, or any control up the Visual Tree, that wants to 
    // handle the event. This is the Custom Routed Event for more info on the 
    // RegisterRoutedEvent method
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597876(v=vs.100).aspx

    public static readonly RoutedEvent decreaseEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("SettingDecreaseEvent", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(UpDownUc));

    public static readonly RoutedEvent increaseEvent =
EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("SettingIncreasaeEvent", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(UpDownUc));

    // Create RoutedEventHandler
    // This adds the Custom Routed Event to the WPF Event System and allows it to be 
    // accessed as a property from within xaml if you so desire

    public event RoutedEventHandler SettingDecrease
    {
        add { AddHandler(decreaseEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(decreaseEvent, value); }
    }

    public event RoutedEventHandler SettingIncrease
    {
        add { AddHandler(increaseEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(increaseEvent, value); }
    }
    // When the Save button on the User Control is clicked, use RaiseEvent to fire the 
    // Custom Routed Event   
    private void HandleButtonClick1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Raise the custom routed event, this fires the event from the UserControl
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(UpDownUc.decreaseEvent));
    }

    private void HandleButtonClick2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Raise the custom routed event, this fires the event from the UserControl
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(UpDownUc.increaseEvent));
    }
}
```

I use this user control in `MainWindow.xaml`

```
<local:UpDownUc   x:Name="elevUpDown" ></local:UpDownUc>
```

and in MainWindow.cs  I register the event

```
            // Register the Bubble Event Handler 
        AddHandler(UpDownUc.decreaseEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(elDownStepTgBtn_MouseLeftButtonDown));
       //i need to create another instance but if use the code below ,rises events are the same
```

AddHandler(azUpDown.increaseEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(elUpStepTgBtn_MouseLeftButtonDown));

the implementations

```
   private void elDownStepTgBtn_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpDownUc.vm.val = Math.Round(UpDownUc.vm.val - Parameters.upDownStepVal, 2);

    }

    private void elUpStepTgBtn_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpDownUc.vm.val = Math.Round(UpDownUc.vm.val + Parameters.upDownStepVal, 2);

    }
```

this works correctly , but the problem is : when I create the new instance an exception occures

```
the routed evnt named SettingDecreaseEvent for ownerType UpDownUc already used
```

if I mean it . acctuly I  just want to reuse a usercontrol that has implemented routed event.
can anyone explain to me what happend  , thanks a lot

Comment: @Clemens but when i use 'static' instead , i have to access the usercontrol event just by class name in Mainwindow (when I register the event ) , I want to access the usercontrol by name because i have two instance of them

Comment: `public  readonly RoutedEvent ...` must be `public static readonly RoutedEvent ...`. See [How to: Create a Custom Routed Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-create-a-custom-routed-event?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). There is also a naming convention, to which the fields should be named `SettingDecreaseEvent` and `SettingIncreaseEvent`. Finally, use `nameof(SettingDecrease)` and `nameof(SettingIncrease)` to avoid typographic errors like `"SettingIncreasaeEvent"` - which should have been `"SettingIncrease"`.

Comment: Besides that, you only access the non-static SettingDecrease and SettingIncrease events, not their static backing fields: `elevUpDown.SettingDecrease +=  elDownStepTgBtn_MouseLeftButtonDown;`

Comment: @Clemens, I read the link an correct my mistake , but the problem remains, I need to use several instance of this usercontrol in my mainwindow with different functionality, thanks

Comment: Not sure what stops you from using multiple instances. Perhaps edit the question and show us your current code.

Answer (score 0):

The events are called `SettingDecrease` and `SettingIncrease`.

Use the `nameof` operator to avoid typos when you register them:

```
public partial class UpDownUc : UserControl
{
    public UpDownUc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Create RoutedEvent
    // This creates a static property on the UserControl, SettingsConfirmedEvent, which 
    // will be used by the Window, or any control up the Visual Tree, that wants to 
    // handle the event. This is the Custom Routed Event for more info on the 
    // RegisterRoutedEvent method
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597876(v=vs.100).aspx

    public static readonly RoutedEvent decreaseEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(nameof(SettingDecrease), RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(UpDownUc));

    public static readonly RoutedEvent increaseEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(nameof(SettingIncrease), RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
        typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(UpDownUc));

    // Create RoutedEventHandler
    // This adds the Custom Routed Event to the WPF Event System and allows it to be 
    // accessed as a property from within xaml if you so desire

    public event RoutedEventHandler SettingDecrease
    {
        add { AddHandler(decreaseEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(decreaseEvent, value); }
    }

    public event RoutedEventHandler SettingIncrease
    {
        add { AddHandler(increaseEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(increaseEvent, value); }
    }
    // When the Save button on the User Control is clicked, use RaiseEvent to fire the 
    // Custom Routed Event   
    private void HandleButtonClick1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Raise the custom routed event, this fires the event from the UserControl
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(decreaseEvent));
    }

    private void HandleButtonClick2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Raise the custom routed event, this fires the event from the UserControl
        RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(increaseEvent));
    }
}
```